# Unity apk not working

Tags: unity-game-engine, build, apk

I made a very simple game, adjusted player settings and external tools.  switched platform to android. I can play my game with Unity remote on my phone.
When I build it's installed in phone, but when I launch app to start playing a black screen appears and then closes immediately.

Comment: Can you post the logcat? It'll help us identify the issue

Comment: Sometimes a build can fail and rebulding the same project will succeed.

Comment: Hive us a bit more detail. Might be worth to fire up logcat to see the log from your phone.  In terminal launch with your phone connected adb logcat -s Unity

Comment: after your message I looked for logcat. it is just like below. shoul I remove unity and reinstall it?                                                          invalid serialized file version.file:"/mnt/asec/com.dene.oyun1-1/base.apk/assets/bin/data/globalmanagers".Expected version 5.3.4f1. actual version 5.3.3f1

Comment: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1fault addr 0x0 in tid 17748 (com.dene.oyun.1)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem as you did with identical logcat message.
If you haven't done so, you should uninstall Unity completely -> restart your computer -> reinstall Unity. That did it for me, hopefully, it works for you as well.